# SQLAlchemy 2.0 migration: how to turn on warn_20

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pytest

I'm trying to migrate my project to SQLA 2.0. [The docs say to turn on sqlalchemy_warn_20](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/changelog/migration_20.html#migration-to-2-0-step-two-turn-on-removedin20warnings), but I can't figure out where/how to do this.

Specifically, where does this go:

```sh
SQLALCHEMY_WARN_20=1 python -W always::DeprecationWarning
```

I tried entering the tests folder and running

```sh
SQLALCHEMY_WARN_20=1 python -W always::DeprecationWarning pytest
```

Didn't work. I tried some other similar combinations. I'm not sure what else to try.

Comment: Can you run pytest as a module: `SQLALCHEMY_WARN_20=1 python -W always::DeprecationWarning -m pytest`

Comment: This worked! Thanks! Idk how to mark the correct answer or label the question solved

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The warnings are controlled at two levels:

##### 1. the Python level

Python 3 suppresses DeprecationWarnings by default, so we need to enable them either by invoking the interpreter with `-W always` (or some variant)

```
python -W always my_app.py
```

or by setting the PYTHONWARNINGS environment variable to "always".

##### 2. the SQLAlchemy level

The actual SQLAlchemy version 2.0 deprecation warnings are enabled by setting the environment variable `SQLALCHEMY_WARN_20=1`. You can do that at the command line as

```
SQLALCHEMY_WARN_20=1 python -W always my_app.py
```

##### Note re: pytest

Although pytest is often invoked by just using `pytest` it can also be invoked as `python -m pytest` so the above would be

```
SQLALCHEMY_WARN_20=1 python -W always -m pytest
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to bother making sure your environment is set and/or don't want to remember to pass flags to `python`, you can also put the following in the Python code itself:

```
import os
import sys
import warnings

os.environ['SQLALCHEMY_WARN_20'] = 'yes'
if not sys.warnoptions:
    warnings.simplefilter("default")
```

You can put this at the top of your script just after the interpreter line of your script/app or if it's a package and you want anyone that imports it to see the warnings, you can put it in the top-level `__init__.py`. Either way should cause it to take effect globally from that point forward

Make sure you you put it before any other imports if you're doing this for a package or module, otherwise you may miss warnings that would occur when the individual modules are imported